# How to SELECT "closest" rows from another table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, greatest-n-per-group, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I have two tables, `map1` and `map2`, there are multiple possible combinations between the columns `map1.id1` and `map2.id2`.

I have tried the below query:

```
SELECT map1.id1, map2.id2, MIN(ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)),map2.g2
FROM map1, map2
WHERE ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2) < 2
GROUP BY map1.id1,map2.g2,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
ORDER BY map1.id1,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
```

#### Current output

Multiple rows for `id1`:

```
id1   id2   min               g2
----  ----  ----------------  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6116   338  1.8122154049353   "0102000020E610000002000000590E3EDEF5AB23409255B6B4BF1B4A4031197DBBDBAB23404AF663EEB51B4A40"
6116   645  1.82162999509807  "0102000020E61000000300000057900B73277D2340A1675831011E4A4094C55801197D23406A204C40021E4A40B0CFF7AE9C7C234079AAE8B4131E4A40"
6116   674  1.82397666934862  "0102000020E610000002000000AC0E6F8C53B723405B80118F1F1E4A404EFF48C78BB723406C9159620A1E4A40"
  65   695  1.22999509807     "01456020E61000000300000057900B73277D2340A1675831011E4A4094C55801197D23406A204C40021E4A40B0CFF7AE9C7C234079AAE8B4131E4A40"
  65   689  1.556666934862    "0202000020E610000002000000AC0E6F8C53B723405B80118F1F1E4A404EFF48C78BB723406C9159620A1E4A40"
--  many more ...
```

#### Desired output

I wanted to SELECT only 1st 1 or 2 rows for for each `id1` - as defined by the minimum [Hausdorff distance](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html):

```
id1   id2   min               g2
----  ----  ----------------  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6116   338  1.8122154049353   "0102000020E610000002000000590E3EDEF5AB23409255B6B4BF1B4A4031197DBBDBAB23404AF663EEB51B4A40"
6116   645  1.82162999509807  "0102000020E61000000300000057900B73277D2340A1675831011E4A4094C55801197D23406A204C40021E4A40B0CFF7AE9C7C234079AAE8B4131E4A40"
  65   695  1.22999509807     "01456020E61000000300000057900B73277D2340A1675831011E4A4094C55801197D23406A204C40021E4A40B0CFF7AE9C7C234079AAE8B4131E4A40"
  65   689  1.556666934862    "0202000020E610000002000000AC0E6F8C53B723405B80118F1F1E4A404EFF48C78BB723406C9159620A1E4A40"
```

Related answer on gis.SE to illustrate the term "Hausdorff distance":

- [Similarity between two or more trajectories](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116523/7244)

Comment: `I wanted to SELECT only 1st 1 or 2 rows for a specific id1` .. "1st" by what definition? What you show is neither the smallest Hausdorff distance, nor the smallest `id2`

Comment: 1st in terms of  order by id1

Comment: Your description, your "desired result" and your comment don't add up. Please present a consistent question.

Comment: I am doing a matching from id1 to id2, from each id1 there could be multiple matches to id2 based on the Hausdorff distance(which should be less than 2), so I wanted to select only top 2 games. Am I able to explain it clearly?

Comment: Not clear to me, no. "Top 2" by what definition? Probably by Hausdorff distance, but your "desired result" says otherwise.

Comment: Yes, maybe by Hausdorff distance, please suggest.

Comment: I edited the question based on assumptions. That part would be *your* job. And added an according answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would achieve it:

```
SELECT m1.id1, m2.*
FROM   map1 m1
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ST_HausdorffDistance(m1.g1, m2.g2) AS h_dist, m2.id2, m2.g2
   FROM   map2 m2
   WHERE  ST_HausdorffDistance(m1.g1, m2.g2) < 2
   ORDER  BY 1, 2
   LIMIT  2
   ) m2;
```

Returns 1 or 2 rows for every row in `map1`, extended with the top 2 corresponding row(s) in `map2` (as defined by minimum Hausdorff distance) and the said Hausdorff distance between them. If there is no row with Hausdorff distance < 2 in `map2`, no row is returned.

Key element is the `LATERAL` subquery. There are variants of this query, depending on exact (missing) requirements. Related:

- [OFFSET and LIMIT on complex query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125958/offset-and-limit-on-complex-query/125959#125959)
- [How to make DISTINCT ON faster in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/177162/how-to-make-distinct-on-faster-in-postgresql/177174#177174)
- [How to speed up querying last values in a time series?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/202248/how-to-speed-up-querying-last-values-in-a-time-series/202532#202532)
- [Optimise a LATERAL JOIN query on a big table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143044/optimise-a-lateral-join-query-on-a-big-table/143065#143065)

I wouldn't know of any way to use an index here. So this is going to be an expensive query.

Comment: Thank you for correction and providing the link, it helped me to learn the concept. Also, I was expecting the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

In postgres you can use LIMIT to limit the number of rows returned.

```
SELECT map1.id1, map2.id2, MIN(ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)),map2.g2
FROM map1, map2
WHERE ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2) < 2
GROUP BY map1.id1,map2.g2,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
ORDER BY map1.id1,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
LIMIT 1
```

Adding that to the query will limit it to how many rows you specify and the example I provided will just return the first row.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html

Comment: I have multiple id1 and id2 combination, that was just for an example, I have updated the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

To get your desired output, this might work. However, your result output does not match your explanation.

```
with a as (
    SELECT map1.id1, map2.id2, MIN(ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)) min,map2.g2
    FROM map1, map2
    WHERE ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2) < 2
    GROUP BY map1.id1,map2.g2,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
    ORDER BY map1.id1,map2.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
), b as (
    SELECT id1, MIN(min) min 
    FROM a
    GROUP BY id1
)
SELECT a.* 
FROM a
INNER JOIN b on a.min = b.min AND a.id1 = b.id1
INNER JOIN map1 on map1.id1 = a.id1
INNER JOIN map2 on map2.id2 = a.id2
ORDER BY a.id1,a.id2, ST_HausdorffDistance(map1.g1, map2.g2)
;
```