# Add row from table B based on minimum distance between table A and B

Tags: postgresql, postgis, nearest-neighbor, lateral-join

I am a beginner with PostgreSQL and have two tables A and B, both with multiple columns, including a point column (geom):

TableA includes a given 'ID', geom, etc , TableB is a "DB" of locations with a 'name' column, geom, etc...

**Need to find for each TableA.id what is the the 'name' (row columns) and distance of the closest location  in TableB.**

already could calculate the distance between all points of TableA and TableB with :

```
ST_DistanceSpheroid(pointA,pointB,[SPHEROID])
```

But the best could build so far, is a select query where provides for each `TAbleA.ID` all distances and respective names from TableB - does not find the minimum for each ID only.

**While needed to have the new calculated columns (distance and name) added to Table A.**

It is not yet clear to me how to work with data output when using "select" vs an actual table data output. or use of views.

Comment: to add, there is no relationship whatsoever like an ID, between columns of Table A and B

Comment: Please provide proper table definitions as `CREATE TABLE` scripts. That's the canonical form to define a table, and we can use it directly to run tests. Ideally provide a fiddle. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [nearest-neighbor](/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbor) classic. The basic solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA a
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT b.name, b.geom <-> a.geom AS dist
   FROM   tableB b
   ORDER  BY dist
   LIMIT  1
   ) b;
```

Be sure to have a [spatial GiST index](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#gist_indexes) on `tableB(geom)`:

```
CREATE INDEX b_geom_gist_idx ON tableB USING GIST (geom);
```

Related:

- [How to SELECT "closest" rows from another table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237066/how-to-select-closest-rows-from-another-table/237134#237134)

Recommended reading:

- https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/knn.html
- The manual about the [distance operator `<->`](https://www.postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)

About the `LATERAL` join:

- [What is the difference between LATERAL JOIN and a subquery in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/939860)

Comment: thanks, really worked! plus the additional links.
Next time will provide table definitions and Postgres version. Fiddle, need to look what is...